# ASM cannot pass 'Type.INT_TYPE' as constant Bootstrap Method Argument

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, invokedynamic, jvm-bytecode

Consider the following code that is meant to generate an `invokedynamic` instruction using ASM:

```
// BOOTSTRAP = new Handle(->
// CallSite bootstrap(MethodHandles.Lookup caller, String name, MethodType methodType, Class<?> someClass)

mv.visitInvokeDynamicInsn("foo", "(I)I", BOOTSTRAP, Type.INT_TYPE);
```

When decompiling the generated class using ASMifier, the relevant line becomes

```
mv.visitInvokeDynamicInsn("foo", "(I)I", new Handle(/* SNIP (same as BOOTSTRAP) */),
                          Type.getType("LI;"));
                                       ¯¯¯¯¯
```

As you can see, the `Type.INT_TYPE` has turned into a literal reference to a reference type named `I`. As this doesn't exist, the JVM complains at runtime with `java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: I`.

What I wanted to do instead was pass `int.class` (the `Class` instance for the primitive type `int`, or the value of the `Integer.TYPE` constant) to my `bootstrap` method as the argument for `someClass`. However, it seems like ASM did not properly understand or support this.

Can this be considered an ASM bug, and is there a workaround for this?

Comment: This seems like a bug. Please report it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Brett Kail pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38927375/2711488), it is impossible to encode a `Class` constant for a primitive type. When you use a literal like `int.class` in source code, the compiler will encode it as read operation of the field `java.lang.Integer.TYPE`, which contains the desired `Class` object. For annotations, it is possible, because the annotation value is encoded to point to a `CONSTANT_Utf8_info` containing a *return descriptor* rather than a `CONSTANT_Class_info` (see [JVM spec §4.7.16.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.16.1-200-C.1)).

Since encoded static arguments to bootstrap methods require `Class` objects to be encoded as `CONSTANT_Class_info`, they do not support primitive types. See [JVM spec §4.7.23](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.23-300-D.1-C):

> Each entry in the bootstrap_arguments array must be a valid index into the constant_pool table. The constant_pool entry at that index must be a `CONSTANT_String_info`, `CONSTANT_Class_info`, `CONSTANT_Integer_info`, `CONSTANT_Long_info`, `CONSTANT_Float_info`, `CONSTANT_Double_info`, `CONSTANT_MethodHandle_info`, or `CONSTANT_MethodType_info` structure…

A work-around would be to add a convention, e.g. always encode the array type of the desired type and extract the element type in the bootstrap method. Or encode the desired type as the return type of a `CONSTANT_MethodType_info`. The latter has the advantage of even supporting `void.class`.

Answer (score 4):

I do not believe it is possible to pass a primitive type as a bootstrap method argument because it is not possible to encode them in the class file.  Per the JVM spec, class arguments are represented as [CONSTANT_Class_info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.1), which can only represent names in [internal form](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.2.1), not as a [descriptor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3).

**Edit:** There is a [proposal](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~jrose/values/shady-values.html#enhanced-constants) to support primitive type constants:

> This minimal prototype adopts this answer, using semicolon `;` (ASCII
>   decimal code 59) as the escape character. Thus, the types `int.class`
>   and `void.class` may now be obtained class-file constants with the UTF8
>   strings "`;I`" and "`;V`". The choice of semicolon is natural here, since
>   a class name cannot contain a semicolon (unless it is an array type),
>   and descriptor syntax is often found following semicolons in class
>   files.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a dynamic constant to load the field once, and feed the dynamic constant in where you would otherwise use `Type.getType()`, you can get an effect almost exactly like having primitive class constants directly in the class file.

There's a method which is specifically designed to facilitate this on `java.lang.invoke.ConstantBootstraps`. It's called `primitiveClass`. It is used like this:

```java
ConstantDynamic intClassConstant =
    new ConstantDynamic(
        "I", 
        "Ljava/lang/Class;", 
        new Handle(
            Opcodes.H_INVOKESTATIC,
            "java/lang/invoke/ConstantBootstraps",
            "primitiveClass",
            // method descriptor strings can get long, apologies...
            "(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;",
            false
        ));
```

Then, use that `intClassConstant` constant value anywhere you would want to use `Type.getType(int.class)`. This works for any primitive type and `void`.

Comment: Too much indirection. Consider using [`new ConstantDynamic("I", "Ljava/lang/Class;", new Handle(Opcodes.H_INVOKESTATIC, "java/lang/invoke/ConstantBootstraps", "primitiveClass", "(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;", false))`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/ConstantBootstraps.html#primitiveClass%28java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup,java.lang.String,java.lang.Class%29).

Comment: You're right, that's a better solution. I'll update my answer.